# Возможность приостановить один Start для первоочерёдного выполнения другого Start?

Tags: unity3d

Собственно сабж. Возможно ли? Дело в том что у меня есть некая проблема с очерёдностью загрузок разных объектов, так как я сначала не пределил этому внимание. Сейчас уже не охотно перелопачивать всё.

Comment: Сделай awake...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, о Awake я знаю, он занят.  О порядке загрузке функций я знаю, и о том что можно настроить загрузки всех Start с верху в низ по объектом, но сабж остался открытым!

Comment: Крч, думаю лучше перелопатить тот бред и сделать норм очередь загрузок данных

Comment: Одна точка входа у система с одним start который все инитит. По другому никто лучше не придумал, так чтобы потом не жрать говна ложками.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно проще будет решить эту проблему с помощью [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) и я советую попробовать сначала именно этот способ.

Но и сам вопрос, конечно, является порождением не правильной архитектуры - не должны `Start` зависеть друг от друга, попробуй переосмыслить этот момент, и максимально избавиться от зависимостей в загрузках. Если интересно, изучите вопрос Dependency injection, или хотя бы посмотрите примеры разнообразных объектов-менеджеров, которых полно в каждом туториале.

Отвечая на вопрос, можно ли приостановить один Start до выполнения другого `Start` - можно. `Start` может быть `Coroutines`, если возвращает `IEnumerator`, в таком случае, выполнение такого метода можно приостановить до наступления какого-то условия. В контексте вопроса этим условием может быть, успешная отработка другого `Start`. Дальше два класса, которые это реализуют

```
public class HighPriorityScript : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public bool isStarted = false;

    void Start() {
        // Код инициализации

        isStarted = true;
    }
}
```

```
public class LowPriorityScript : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public HighPriorityScript highPriorityScript ; 

    IEnumerator Start() {
        while (!highPriorityScript.isStarted)
            yield return null;
    
        // Код инициализации
    }
}
```